# SPARQL: Query to get all Instances of two classes that share the same connections to a third class

Tags: sparql, ontology

Im trying to understand the capabilities of SPARQL an im wondering if this kind of query is possible:

[Diagram of my Ontology structure](http://www.pictureupload.de/originals/pictures/101012113644_ProblemDiagram.jpeg) (sorry, Im not allowed to post pictures yet)

I want to get all instances of class A and B that have connections to the same Instances of class B. So some kind of:

```
Select ?a, ?c
Where
{
 ?a myOntology:ab ?c .
 ?c myOntology:cb ?B .
}
```

Which would give me:

```
A:1 C:1
A:2 C:1 (with B:2)
A:2 C:1 (with B:3)
```

(Where the letter is the class and the number the instance, counted from the top)

But with the difference that I only want the ones that have exactly the same related instances of B:

```
A:2 C:1 (with B:2 and B:3)
```

Is that possible or do I have to use external logic to get that?

I would be pleased for any answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! if you can use NOT EXISTS.

SPARQL, like SQL, does not have a universal quantifier, but you can do with nested NOT EXISTS-s.

Your query is, in pseudo SPARQL, "Give me all pairs (a,c) such that a-b-c such that no other bb such that a-bb and not bb-c --- and vise verse: bb-c and not a-bb":

```
PREFIX : <http://test/>
SELECT ?a ?b ?c
WHERE 
{ ?a :ab ?b .
  ?b :bc ?c .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS
  { ?a :ab ?bb .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS
    {  ?bb :bc ?c . } 
  }
  ## vise verse:
  FILTER NOT EXISTS
  { ?bb :bc ?c .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS
    {  ?a :ab ?bb . } 
  }
}
```

Running it on

```
@prefix : <http://test/> .
:a1 :ab :b1 .
:a1 :ab :b2 .
:a2 :ab :b2 .
:a2 :ab :b3 .
:b2 :bc :c1 .
:b3 :bc :c1 .
```

gives

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| a                | b                | c                |
==========================================================
| <http://test/a2> | <http://test/b3> | <http://test/c1> |
| <http://test/a2> | <http://test/b2> | <http://test/c1> |
----------------------------------------------------------
```